# Obfuscate email in a way it is not recoverable but still usable

Tags: php, email, hash

Probably a stupid question, but I need to ask anyway.
I'm working on a research, which involves emailing fake phishing emails to participants.
At the beginning, I would have a database of email addresses.
Because of ethical considerations, I would like somehow to hash the email addresses in a way, that later they would not be recoverable even if I want to.
For example:
I want to send an email to
john.doe@mail.com 
The email would lead to a page, where I would collect some data (when was it visited, what did he did on the page), so basically I would store email address and its actions in a database.

I could store the hash of the email address in this database, so in the end I wouldn't have his address, but the problem is at a later stage I will need to email him a second time, and record those actions as well...

Now the problem is:

1. If I hash his email address and store it this way in the database, a
   simple re-hash of the original database would reveal the recipient.
2. If I hash his email with a random salt, I could not link his old and
       new actions together.
3. I need to be able to tell honestly that there
       is no way I can link real email addresses and real people to the
       database entries. (I just need the results anyway)

Comment: When you say you can rehash the original database, do you mean that you keep the plain email addresses in there?

Comment: I meant, that if someone would take the original list of email addresses, would hash each of them and then by comparing the hashes he generated, tothe hashes stored in the database, they could link real persons to database entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't keep the email address usable and also make it impossible to recover it. If you need to be able to decode/recover the email address to send an email at a later date, then there's no way to make it unrecoverable. That's a contradiction in terms. You would need to do something like use a third party to create per-user tokens, but then the third party would need to store the token and the email. There's no avoiding it: someone has to store the email.

The best solution is just to encrypt any sensitive data, including personally identifiable information (PII). If you want to be hyper-paranoid about it, you could throw away the key at the end of your project. But you have to keep it in the meantime, if you really need to be able to use the encrypted information (like the email address).

Also, be aware that what you are doing may have legal implications (both the sending of bogus phishing emails and the storage of PII). You should speak to a lawyer in whatever jurisdiction(s) is/are relevant.

Comment: So for example, I would use a salt while hashing those values, and I could re-use the salt again, and then dispose of the salt so I could not re-do the hashing ever again.

Comment: @GyulaSoós No, hashing makes the email unrecoverable. If you just need to match an email address to the records, then that's much easier. But if you need, for example, to email user number 17, then you need to know that user's email address. But you can't recover that from a hash. You need to encrypt it and decrypt it, not hash it. Keep in mind that hashing is *not* encryption, and encryption is *not* hashing.

Comment: The list of email addresses in this case would be accessible at any time. What I wanted to achieve, that if I send an email to an address, I would make a new "name", an ID for him. And later, I would repeat the hash, and because that would lead to the same result, I could update the records for that ID.

Comment: I just had an idea.... what if, the salt, or a key if I will use encryption, would be provided by two persons. One would be me, and the other would be a trustee within the organisation. This way they can't get the same hash without me, and I could not do it without them.

Comment: You can get very fancy with it, like you're describing, but it boils down to this: hashes work only one way. If you are okay with a scenario in which somebody says, "Look up records for the user with email blah@example.com," then a salted hash is perfect. If, on the other hand, you need to be able to query your database and email your users - without being prompted with their email addresses - then you can't use a hash. You could use encryption and, like you suggested, split the key between two people. That's probably overkill, and it still means *the email has to be recoverable somehow*.